# Commit to SVN from parent folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have file that I wish to commit from parent folder.
This runs just fine:

```
C:\Development\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidDev>svn commit --force-log -F BuildNumber.txt
```

But I need to run the command from external folder, the reason is that I have build machine that can only run command from parent folder. So... When running this:

```
C:\Development\AndroidStudioProjects>svn commit --force-log -F AndroidDev/BuildNumber.txt
```

I get an error:

```
svn: E155007: 'C:\Development\AndroidStudioProjects' is not a working copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, `C:\Development\AndroidStudioProjects` is not a working copy and you haven't specified the path to the working copy.

The correct command should look like this one:

`svn commit AndroidDev --force-log -F AndroidDev/BuildNumber.txt`

`svn commit` reference in SVNBook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html

Don't forget to read a manual before asking questions. If you have any questions about Subversion, it makes sense to check the documentation first. I suggest reading SVNBook http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/ and TortoiseSVN manual https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html

Comment: I still get the same error:
svn: E155007: 'C:\Development\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidStudioProjects' is not a working copy

Comment: @dim sry, it had to be `AndroidDev`.

Comment: Oh!!! Now it works... I don`t know why people downvoted my question, I really new to SVN and you did helped me alot